# Counting number of Childs for a node using libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 version 2.6.32 which doesn't have function xmlChildElementCount so I wrote my custom function which is given below

```
int child_node_count(const xmlNodePtr nodePtr){
    register int i = 0;
    for(xmlNodePtr node = nodePtr->children;node;node = node->next,i++);
    return i --;
}
```

Now when I've a node in this fashion `<node>somevalue</node>` I was expecting the function to return 0 count but I'm getting count as 1 is this a mistake in my code or somevalue is really a child of `<node>`. (I don't know how libxml2 represents XML as )

Comment: i think here you are passing the pointer of root node ..better you pass the pointer of your desire node to calculate its child node..

Comment: I passed pointer for the `<node>` tag itself still it returns count as one probably a code mistake but I'm not able to figure it out :(

Comment: why you are taking register ? why you are decrementing i ? else code is fine.. may be something was misunderstood from libxml2 code

Comment: Register was just to make it fast (may not be required but I actually got loop hole in my code i should return `--i` not `i--` :) Decrementing because `i` will be incremented one more than existing number of nodes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `somvalue` really is a node - a node of type XML_TEXT_NODE. See here for a complete list of types of nodes you may encounter: http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlElementType.

You might be looking for `xmlChildElementCount` ? See: http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlChildElementCount

Answer (score 0):

To match the behaviour of the official `xmlChildElementCount` you should only increment the counter when `node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE` so you don't count text nodes and other types of non-element node.

You should also accept non-const `xmlNodePtr` arguments and return 0 if `nodePtr == NULL`